# UIGestureRecognizer rotate UIVIew with CGAffineTransformRotate and with angle between zeroPoint(0, "some number") and gesture pan point

Tags: ios, swift, math

I have a simple task: rotate UIView on user touch. Top of my view must always pointed on finger touch.
I tried to do it with next code:

```
func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let currentPoint = recognizer.locationInView(self.superview)
        let dx = currentPoint.x - self.center.x
        let dy = currentPoint.y - self.center.y - self.radius
        let angle = atan2(dy, dx)
        var deg = angle * CGFloat(2.0 / M_PI)
        if deg < 0 {
            deg += 360.0
        }
        let transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.rotateView.transform, angle)
        self.rotateView.transform = transform
        println("x: \(currentPoint.x), y: \(currentPoint.y), angle: \(angle), deg: \(deg)")
    }
```

But I have a wrong angle as you can see below

> ```
> x: 235.0, y: 426.5, angle: 0.616667, deg: 0.392582
> x: 221.0, y: 431.5, angle: 0.761626, deg: 0.484866
> x: 212.0, y: 433.5, angle: 0.858078, deg: 0.54627
> x: 203.0, y: 436.5, angle: 0.973115, deg: 0.619504
> x: 196.0, y: 437.5, angle: 1.05952, deg: 0.67451
> x: 187.0, y: 439.5, angle: 1.18336, deg: 0.753351
> x: 179.0, y: 439.5, angle: 1.29117, deg: 0.821982
> x: 168.0, y: 439.5, angle: 1.45047, deg: 0.9234
> x: 143.0, y: 439.5, angle: 1.82228, deg: 1.1601
> x: 122.0, y: 437.5, angle: 2.10547, deg: 1.34038
> x: 108.0, y: 435.5, angle: 2.26738, deg: 1.44346
> x: 96.0, y: 429.5, angle: 2.42129, deg: 1.54144
> x: 80.0, y: 423.5, angle: 2.5815, deg: 1.64343
> x: 73.0, y: 418.5, angle: 2.66274, deg: 1.69515
> x: 68.0, y: 415.5, angle: 2.71183, deg: 1.7264
> x: 60.0, y: 409.5, angle: 2.79456, deg: 1.77907
> x: 56.0, y: 406.5, angle: 2.83288, deg: 1.80347
> x: 47.0, y: 397.5, angle: 2.9309, deg: 1.86587
> x: 40.0, y: 384.0, angle: 3.05294, deg: 1.94356
> x: 26.0, y: 359.0, angle: -3.03503, deg: 358.068
> x: 18.0, y: 342.0, angle: -2.92442, deg: 358.138
> x: 12.0, y: 326.0, angle: -2.83205, deg: 358.197
> x: 8.0, y: 312.0, angle: -2.75807, deg: 358.244
> x: 6.0, y: 303.0, angle: -2.71317, deg: 358.273
> x: 5.0, y: 296.0, angle: -2.67881, deg: 358.295
> x: 3.0, y: 286.0, angle: -2.63395, deg: 358.323
> x: 2.0, y: 281.0, angle: -2.61273, deg: 358.337
> x: 2.0, y: 277.0, angle: -2.59407, deg: 358.349
> x: 2.0, y: 272.0, angle: -2.57132, deg: 358.363
> x: 2.0, y: 269.0, angle: -2.55798, deg: 358.372
> x: 3.0, y: 266.0, angle: -2.54192, deg: 358.382
> x: 4.0, y: 264.0, angle: -2.53029, deg: 358.389
> x: 6.0, y: 262.0, angle: -2.51563, deg: 358.398
> x: 8.0, y: 260.0, angle: -2.5009, deg: 358.408
> x: 11.0, y: 254.0, angle: -2.46631, deg: 358.43
> x: 13.0, y: 250.0, angle: -2.44352, deg: 358.444
> x: 16.0, y: 244.0, angle: -2.4098, deg: 358.466
> x: 19.0, y: 238.0, angle: -2.3767, deg: 358.487
> x: 24.0, y: 228.0, angle: -2.32303, deg: 358.521
> x: 25.0, y: 222.0, angle: -2.29921, deg: 358.536
> x: 28.0, y: 214.0, angle: -2.26265, deg: 358.56
> x: 28.0, y: 206.0, angle: -2.2387, deg: 358.575
> x: 29.0, y: 199.0, angle: -2.21521, deg: 358.59
> x: 30.0, y: 191.0, angle: -2.19018, deg: 358.606
> x: 31.0, y: 182.0, angle: -2.16401, deg: 358.622
> x: 32.0, y: 174.0, angle: -2.14163, deg: 358.637
> x: 34.0, y: 168.0, angle: -2.12118, deg: 358.65
> x: 35.0, y: 161.0, angle: -2.10286, deg: 358.661
> x: 36.0, y: 155.0, angle: -2.08731, deg: 358.671
> x: 36.0, y: 152.0, angle: -2.08147, deg: 358.675
> x: 37.0, y: 149.0, angle: -2.07233, deg: 358.681
> x: 39.0, y: 146.0, angle: -2.05992, deg: 358.689
> x: 39.0, y: 146.0, angle: -2.05992, deg: 358.689
> ```

And I don't know why my angle is always ~385.
Anyone have any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: Keep it concise. Show less lines of output code but make sure it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Glancing at your code, it looks like you're converting from radians to degrees incorrectly.  360 degrees = 2π radians, so...

```
var deg = angle * CGFloat(180.0 / M_PI)
```

should fix things.

Hope this helps.